# Dask Memory Leak Workaround

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

When using the Dask dataframe where clause I get a "distributed.worker_memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS" warning.  This happens until the system runs out of memory and swap.  Is there a workaround to this or am I doing something wrong.  The file I'm reading can be found at https://lcb.app.box.com/s/e89t59s0yb558tjoncjsid710oirqbgd?page=1.  You have to read it in with Pandas as save it as a parquet file for Dask to read it.

```
from dask import dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da
from dask.distributed import Client

from pathlib import Path
import os
file_path = Path('../cannabis_data_science/wa/nov_2021')

client = Client(n_workers=2, threads_per_worker=2, memory_limit = '15GB')
client

sale_items_df = dd.read_parquet(path = file_path / 'SaleItems_1.parquet', blocksize = '100MB').reset_index()

#this causes the warning
x = sale_items_df.description.where(sale_items_df.description.isna(), sale_items_df.name).compute()
```

Comment: Sorry you haven't gotten a response. You're likely just running out of memory - string masking operations like this aren't super memory efficient. Generally, "download this huge file, then convert it, then run this code" doesn't count as a [mre]. Check out the dask founder's guide to [crafting minimal bug reports](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports) - it's really helpful, and will make it much more likely that you'll get help specific to your problem. Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado If you read my question carefully, you will see that I a memory leak warning.  This is a reproducible example.  I do run out of memory due to the memory leak that is an issue with Dask.  This is a known issue with Dask and I am asking if there is a workaround.  I have outlined the steps to reproduce the bug so I'm not sure what your problem is with my question.

Comment: I don't have a problem with it - I'm pointing you to an article which gives tips which make it more likely you'll get help. I'm not going to download a large unknown file onto my laptop to help you. But someone else might :)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I posed the same question to a Dask forum and received some constructive advice. I'm sure that person didn't download the file and run the code. I talked to someone in person and they gave me some constructive advice without downloading the file or running the code.  So you seem to be the only one that has a problem with the way I asked my question.  If I hadn't given a link to the file someone would have commented on that; which is a comment that I often see when someone asks for advice.

Comment: Glad you got help!

Comment: @UFOSoftware, could you share what answer/advice you got?

Comment: @Khashir Recently, I found that the problem is with Dask and the parquet file.  Pandas a PyArrow can both read the entire parquet file but Dask has an issue with it.  If I convert the original UTF-16 csv file to UTF-8 Dask is able to read the entire file.